# Only seeing "--" in my case history export tab

Tags: commcare

I have a case property that is updated by two forms in my app. I tried to create a case export that included row #, the caseid, and the case property I'd like to see the history of. When I include the row and case property in the case export, all I see are "--" in the history tab, which I did not expect since most cases have a value (and I would expect a history of the value being updated by the two forms that update the property for at least a few of the cases).

Comment: If your entire Case History export shows `---`, it is most likely  a bug in the system that should be reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the `---` in an export means that that value is missing. As in CommCare never found it in the form or case. This is in contrast to a blank, which means that CommCare found the value, but it was blank or empty.